# Amazon CloudFront: Identify if there have been any updates with the file - Reload file (and re-cache)

Tags: amazon-web-services, caching, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have recently set Cloudfront to cache files (images, css and javascript):

1. It requires me to clear cache manually from within the browser sometimes to get the new file.
2. Caching files within Cloudfront is really tough - A week ago - I tried enabling GZIP compression on Cloudfront and noticed that until I didn't add my file to the "Invalidaion" table - the file wasn't displayed updated on my website. 
   (I cleared cache from my browser and this didn't help either btw)

Is there any "smart" way for caching on Amazon Cloudfront? 
Something like: "if the file has been updated - send the new file (as gzip of course). "

Here are my headers:

```
Request URL:https://abc.cloudfront.net/live/static/rcss/bootstrap3.min.css
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
Remote Address:77.77.77.77:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers    
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/css
Connection: keep-alive
Date: Sun, 07 May 2017 08:14:04 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 26 Apr 2017 08:43:05 GMT
Server: AmazonS3
Content-Encoding: gzip
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront
Via: 1.1 abc.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
X-Amz-Cf-Id: abc-iuxzccRYcxce8LjxzcDeYdasdehHqFJGj80iczxcz8Q4asdDpWg==

Request Headers
Accept:text/css,*/*;q=0.1
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:abc.cloudfront.net
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://example.com/
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36
```

If there is anything else I can add to my post - please do ask.

Comment: *"It requires me to clear cache manually from within the browser sometimes to get the new file."*  That's unrelated to CloudFront, and underscores the nature of the problem you're having -- this is an issue with web caching, generally: when you change content that any entity may have cached, you have to accommodate that, sometimes by changing the name, or by using a different cache-busting tactic.  Some tools and frameworks have built-in techniques for handling this, so if you're using something like that, you might want to mention it here.  And google "cache busting."

Comment: [*"There are two hard problems in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors."*](https://mobile.twitter.com/codinghorror/status/506010907021828096?lang=en)